# Decimals with format()

Tags: python, format

```py
output_a = "{:f}".format(52.7)
print(output_a)
```

Why is the result coming out like this:
`52.700000`

Not like this:
`52.7`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the number of decimal you want to print :

```
print("{:.1f}".format(52.7))
```

> 52.7

By default the number of decimal is 6.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language
[image: Screenshot for 'f']

So if you don't want precision up to 6 decimal point, but only 1 decimal point  then use

```
output_a = "{:.1f}".format(52.7)
print(output_a)
```

Comment: It's my first time to here. Thank you for your kind reply.